# git: squash three last commits together

Tags: git, rebase

I want to squash my 3 last commit together (from ax38aa to ax18aa).

i had

```
commit ax18aa
commit ax28aa
commit ax38aa
commit ax48aa
commit ax58aa
```

**Code**

```
git rebase -i ax48aa
```

but was surprised that when i did **git log** i have only

```
commit ax48aa
commit ax58aa
```

and didn't ask mi the new message for the commit. How can i do? please?
who can help please
Thank youu,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Squash my last X commits together using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git)

Comment: @mnestorov no . I did **git rebase -i ax48aa**

Comment: Does the same result happen when you do `git rebase -i HEAD~3`

Comment: but now in my git log i haven't the **commit ax18aa
commit ax28aa
commit ax38aa** so can't see :/.

Comment: @mnestorov can you help me please?``

Comment: @mnestorov in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git they said that **git rebase -i <after-this-commit>**

Comment: During your interactive rebase, to each commit, what was the command you issued? Did you pick some of the commits? Did you squash all of them?

Comment: i changed all the pick to squash. @mnestorov

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220217/discussion-between-mnestorov-and-jappa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you `squash`ed all of the commits during your interactive rebase, leaving you in a state of `rebasing`. This means that you are currently doing the rebase, but have not finished it and can only see the oldest two commits `ax48aa` and `ax58aa`. The easiest way to get out of this situation is to:

```sh
git rebase --abort
```

This will discard any changes you might have done and will put you in the state before the rebase. If by any chance you still **do not** see all of your 5 commits, then look into the `reflog` with `git reflog`, find the first commit and do `git reset --hard ax18aa`.

Now do a new rebase again, but this time, `pick` the oldest/top most commit of your interactive rebase.

```sh
git rebase -i HEAD~3
# or
git rebase -i ax48aa
```

and then do the following:

```sh
pick ax38aa commit message 3
squash ax28aa commit message 2
squash ax18aa commit message 1
```

This will do what you wanted.

Also keep in mind that after your rebase, you will have a new commit and you will need to **force push** to your remote repo in order for your changes to be uploaded!

Answer (score 3):

That can be done like this:

```
git reset --soft ax38aa
git commit --amend -m "some blahblah"
```

Comment: thank you @eftshift() but i don't want to squash the **ax58aa** the new commit i mean for the squashed commit commit **ax18aa, commit ax28aa, commit ax38aa**

Comment: `git reset --soft ax38aa`

Comment: You also need to add -m before the "some blahblah"